# Multiple answer group & answers asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, helper, checkboxfor, radiobuttonfor

I want to do a single OR multiple answer quiz using radiobuttonfor and checkboxFor, but I cannot make it work. The problem with all example I see is that the Question model also register the SelectedAnswer, but in my case I want each possible answer to be selectable since some questions will have multiples answers, and thus the isSelected property is directly inside the Answer model.

Therefore, for questions with single answers, when I try to create my model using RadioButtonFor(m => m[question].Answers[answerToDisplayId].IsSelected), every answer is in its own group and is not unchecked when I check another answer from that question (basically it behave like a checkBoxFor)

What I currently have: The question model

```
public enum questionfield
{
    Chaser, Beater, Seeker, Contact, Process, Other
};
public enum QuestionDifficulty
{
    Basic, Advanced
};
public enum AnswerType
{
    SingleAnswer, MultipleAnswer
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question name not valid")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public QuestionField Field { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public QuestionDifficulty Difficulty { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsVideo { get; set; }
    public string VideoURL { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public AnswerType AnswerType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String AnswerExplanation { get; set; }
```

Answer model :

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Answertext { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsTrue { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

The view :

```
<div> 
    <!-- For each Question, display a new div with the Title, the question code, the question text, the video if there is one, then the possible answers depending on the type of answers-->
    @using(Html.BeginForm("QuizzResult", "Home"))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="QuizzQuestion">
                <div class="QuizzQuestionTitle">@Model[i].Id : @Model[i].Name</div> @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                <div class="QuizzQuestiontext">@Model[i].QuestionText</div>
                @if(@Model[i].IsVideo)
                {
                    <div class="QuizzQuestionVideoContainer">
                        <iframe class="QuizzQuestionVideo" id="ytplayer" type="text/html"
                                src="@Model[i].VideoURL"
                                frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="RadioButtonAnswers">
                @if (@Model[i].AnswerType == QRefTrain3.Models.AnswerType.SingleAnswer)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Answers.Count; j++)
                    {
                        @Model[i].Answers[j].Answertext @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Answers[j].IsSelected, true)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Answers[j].IsTrue)
                    }
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Validate Answers"/>
    }
</div>
```

The controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult QuizzResult(List<Question> answers)
    {
        foreach(Question a in answers)
        {
            var b = Request.Form[a.Id.ToString()];

        }
        Result result = new Result();
        foreach (Question q in answers)
        {
            result.QuestionsAskedIds.Add(q.Id);
            if (Question.IsGoodAnswer(q))
            {
                result.GoodAnswersIds.Add(q.Id);
            }
        }
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            result.User = Dal.Instance.GetUserByName(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            Dal.Instance.CreateResult(result);
        }

        return View("QuizResult", result);
    }
```

What would be the good way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will see this :

The solution I found was to change the model : Instead of having one IsSelected parameter per answer, add a List selectedAnswers to your Question model. Then, in the view, add your radiobutton like this :

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].SelectedAnswers, Model[i].Answers[j].Id)
```

You will store the id of each selected answer for this question ine the SelectedAnswers list. You can then create your results using this data.